# Where are Hyperledger Fabric events stored?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I understand there is world state and ledger.

1) World state is stored in Level DB or Couch DB 
2) Ledger is stored in the form of LevelDB - /var/hyperledger

How about the events ? Where are they stored ? Especially what will happen when a new peer needs to pull the existing events. I was not able to find any documentation. It will be nice if someone can point me to the right information

Answer (score -1):

A peer can't subscribe to historical events, and they are not stored anywhere in Fabric.

Hyperledger Composer stores transaction details (including events) in the [Historian](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/historian), which you can query to extract event details. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104387/how-to-access-the-eventemitted-field-in-transaction-history-of-hyperledger-fab) for an example.

Comment: it's not true because when using java sdk, after channel initialization it fires the previously fired event. Even after restarting the peer container it still fires that event. It's strange behaviour